# Как мне сделать футер (footer) на всю ширину окна, при ширине html и body 960px?

Tags: html, css

У меня сайт имеет фиксированную ширину - 960 пикселей

```
html, body{
     width: 960px;
}
```

Как мне сделать футер (footer) на всю ширину окна, а не на 960 пикселей? Такое вообще возможно в данной ситуации?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9r4BN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абсолютным позиционированием относительно страницы, чтобы футер был над потоком. При этом пусть последний элемент контента отступом вниз, равным высоте футера, обеспечит нормальное его отображение на странице. Но это ужасно. Вообще, конечно, недальновидно назначать такие правила для html, body.

Answer (score 0):

Создай внутри body контейнер для всего сайта с заданной шириной, а body оставь на всю ширину, блок с футером ниже контейнера сайта, для него делай нужный бэкграунд, а внутри этого блока, блок с контентом футера по ширине равный ширине сайта.